# NestJS уведомления

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

Нужна помощь/подсказка как реализовать функционал уведомлений на сайте. Разрабатывают backend на NestJS, фронт на ReactJS и появилась задачи сделать уведомления на сайте когда тебя лайкают, подписываются или комментируют твои посты. Обычный сервис с созданием и получением уведомлений уже готов, от фронта идет запрос и бек отдает ответ в виде массива с последними уведомлениями. **Задача следующая**: нужно сделать подписку на новые уведомления, когда один пользователь находится на сайте и другой пользователь например лайкает его в это же время, чтобы мгновенно или с интервалом первому пользователю от бекенда пришел объект этого уведомления. На ум приходит WebSocket, long pulling и SSE но нет мыслей как сделать ответ для определенного пользователя. Если кто-то может помочь, подсказать или скинуть ресурс со статьей на подобную реализацию, был бы благодарен

P.S WebSocket на данный момент не хочу использовать т.к приложение не большое и по сути нужны только уведомления

Comment: > P.S WebSocket на данный момент не хочу использовать т.к приложение не большое и по сути нужны только уведомления<br/>
ну и зря,  отвергаешь самый простой вариант

Comment: @Вадим иначе никак не сделать? Просто приложение небольшое, а целый ws запускать для него, не знаю хорошая ли практика

Comment: а long pulling и SSE городить для такого обмена? на js реализовать ws - строк 20. на сервере - ну в зависимости от реализации сервера.

Comment: @Вадим long pulling использовал только чтобы долбить сервер и получать информацию каждые 10 секунд, вне зависимости обновились данные или нет, а ws в проектах с чатами т.к иначе там никак и не сделать. Мысль была через SSE + events, но опять же проблема оповещения определенного пользователя.. Поэтому мне больше совет нужен как это лучше сделать для уведомлений, там функционал простейший, это при входе на сайт через обычный api получение всех уведомлений и уже онлайн режиме, на сайте, если в базе данных добавились данные для конкретного юзера, отправить их на фронт этому юзеру

Comment: дак ws и есть самое простое. чел зашел на сайт - его сессия запомнилась в массиве(листе и т.п.) ктщ-то что-то ввел - по ws передалось на сервер, принялось, просмотр массива - отправка по ws отмеченным в массиве. делов мизер.

Comment: @Вадим понял, спасибо)